Average field intensity in quantum optics
When we transform the electric field into operators $\mathbf{\hat{E}^{(+)}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{E}^{(-)}}$ for the positive and negative frequency components, respectively, what is the correct expression for intensity? In many sources, such as below, intensity is $\langle \mathbf{\hat{E}^{(-)}} \mathbf{\hat{E}^{(+)}} \rangle$, but isn't this dimensionally incorrect, since classically, the definition of intensity is: $I \propto \epsilon_0 c |E|^2$ ?
Below is from page 32 of "Quantum Theory of Optical Coherence" by Roy Glauber:

Also, when computing the average intensity as in the above expression, why is there no integral over time needed (i.e. $\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T$)? Is it included already when taking the ensemble average?
Any clarification/references would be greatly appreciated!

In quantum optics, the average number of photons (or the average rate of photons) is considered to be proportional to the intensity. Therefore, the number operators
$$ \hat{n} = \int \sum_s \hat{a}_s^{\dagger}(\mathbf{k}) \hat{a}_s(\mathbf{k}) \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} , $$
(or its spatial domain equivalent in terms of the electric field operator) can be used to obtain a result that is equivalent (proportional) to the intensity: $\langle\hat{n}\rangle \propto I$. The result can be multiplied by the necessary dimension parameters to get the correct units for the intensity.
One can generalize the number operator to represent the specific experimental conditions by inserting a kernel function that contracts the two ladder operators. In that way one can model the finite integration time and finite integrating area of a detector. In such a case, there would be integrations over time and space incorporated into the expression.
